# What is the 'default' event that, when raised, causes the browser to execute javascript not assigned to an event?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Practically all simple javascript examples show code like

```
<script>
  window.alert('sup');
</script>
```

Which does not make explicit exactly when the browser should execute the script.  However, the code does seem to run at some point...  I feel like it would probably be one of the window/document onload events, but I can't seem to find where this behaviour is specified (or even if it is specified).  ...I suppose, if it is the latter, are there any resources out there that document these sorts of non-specified browser behaviours, or is the best solution available trial and error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the [`async` or `defer` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) on `script` elements, the browser runs JavaScript code that is not inside a function as it encounters it while parsing the document. If there are multiple script elements it runs them in order.

And code that *is* inside a function may still be run without a specific event triggering it if the function is called directly, e.g. the following will define a function and then call it immediately:

```
<script>
  function test() {
    alert("Test");
  }
  test();
</script>
```

Executing script elements in order is an important, predictable behaviour of the browser, because if a script element in the middle of the document happens to do something like a `document.write()` then whatever is written will appear where the script element was. And if the script attempts to manipulate other elements in the document it will only have access to elements *above* the script because the ones below haven't been parsed yet. Also JS in any given script has access to global functions and variables declared in earlier script elements.

> *"I feel like it would probably be one of the window/document onload events"*

It's not. Those events will call functions that are explicitly bound to them, if any are. Other code like you've shown in your question and I've shown above will run *before* the onload event.

---

The `async` and `defer` attributes change things a bit, on browsers that support them. They only relate to `script` tags that refer to external JavaScript resources, e.g.:

```
<script async src="my.js"></script>
```

A full discussion of them is off-topic for this answer, but:

- Using either `async` or `defer` will allow the HTML parser to continue building the page without waiting for the JavaScript code to be run first
- Scripts using `async` may be executed out of order, and are run as soon as they are available
- Scripts using `defer` will be executed in order when the parser has finished building the page
- You can't use both on the same `script` tag; if you do, `async` wins

Comment: it follows, then, that placement within the document affects the behaviour of any calls to the dom.  this feels messy.  ...and where is this behaviour specified?

Comment: @romnempire: Yes, [placement matters](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) (unless you use `async` / `defer` on browsers that support them). *"and where is this behaviour specified"* In [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

Comment: For scripts without the `async` or `defer` attributes (thanks for the edit @T.J.Crowder) the fact that placement affects behaviour may seem a bit messy but it is also completely logical and predictable. I mean what would you have the browser do other than execute scripts top-to-bottom as encounted? It's generally considered bad practice to sprinkle script elements throughout the document. It's reasonably standard practice to put scripts at the bottom of the document, or at the top with code that needs to access the DOM called from a document ready or onload handler.